# Is it possible to figure out why someone was murdered?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've been playing around with Dwarf Fortress' legends mode and was reading about one of the figures. He was murdered at age 23 by someone else. Is there any way to figure out why he was murdered?

Comment: I "improved" the title a bit, this way it is more "fun".

Comment: Let us imagine now a dwarf with the longest of beards in a shack at night, smoking a pipe contemplatively, his brooding face lit up only by the fireplace. Around him are gathered, in silence, several dwarves of every shape and size, including two attractive females; the usual suspects. Their eyes are shifty. The murderer is in the room. Suddenly, the bearded dwarf stands, and exclaims "By Armok, I have it!" He stabs a finger at one of the females. "It was you, Dwarf Ms. Scarlet, on the drawbridge, with the pick axe!" ...Unfortunately, his dwarven thoughts are unable to deduct why. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, based on extensive online research and the fact that none of our Dwarf Fortress vets have chimed in yet, there is no way for you to discover the reason as to why someone was murdered.

Comment: too bad, too. would have added quite the depth...

Comment: It's implied they were murdered for the socks. It is always the socks.